# React: Why am I getting no output after running the .html file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Heyy,JS Page</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id = "root"></div> 
        <script src="index.pack.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to print the statement "Heyy,JS Page" from tag h1 of JS File to html page but nothing gets displayed.

Comment: Your source code in browser will never change after the first render. Source code <> Dom elements :)

Comment: Your code does actually work. What do you mean by "running the .html file"?

Comment: @Andy as you can see I have written a print statement "Heyy,JS Page" in js file and connected it to html so I'm talking about that running. Hope I'm able to clear it :)

Comment: @windmaomao So by that you mean I won't be able to see the print statements of JS file?

Comment: yes, it depends on if you are doing Server side rendering, most likely not. For basic react setup. You will never see dom elements printed in the source code, but if you open Console tab and inspect, you will still see them. That means React by default is working with dynamic elements in the run time.